# Creating calendar data through for loop iteration - Keep getting the wrong day count for the last week

Tags: python, for-loop, methods, return

I'm building a calendar app as part of my main app.  However, I'm having an issue when I create the instances for the days for each week instance.

`calendar.py`:

```
for w in range(0, current_month.getWeeksTotal()):
    current_week = current_month.getWeek(w)
    week_length = current_week.getLength()
    week_label = LabelBlock(calendar_frame, w, 0, width=8, height=1, justify='left', text='Week: ' + str(w + 1))
    for d in range(0, week_length):
        day_label = LabelBlock(calendar_frame, w, d + 1, width=2, height=1, justify='center', text=str(d + 1))
```

`classes_calendar.py`:

```
    # Create a data block for a week
    class WeekBlock:
        def __init__(self, num, length):
            self.num = num
            self.length = length
            self.days = []
    
            for d in range(0, self.length):
                day = DayBlock(d + 1)
                self.days.append(day)
    
        def getDay(self, num):
            return self.days[num - 1]
    
        def getLength(self):
            return self.length


# Create a data block for a month
class MonthBlock:
    def __init__(self, num, days):
        self.num = num
        self.days = days
        self.days_remaining = days
        self.days_remainder = days % 7
        self.weeks = []
        self.weeks_total = 4
        self.months = dict([
            (1, 'January'),
            (2, 'February'),
            (3, 'March'),
            (4, 'April'),
            (5, 'May'),
            (6, 'June'),
            (7, 'July'),
            (8, 'August'),
            (9, 'September'),
            (10, 'October'),
            (11, 'November'),
            (12, 'December')
        ])
        self.name = self.months[num]

        # Create 4 weeks
        for w in range(0, 4):
            week = WeekBlock(w + 1, 7)
            self.weeks.append(week)
            self.days_remaining -= 7

        # Check for a partial week
        if self.days_remainder > 0:
            week = WeekBlock(w + 1, self.days_remaining)
            self.weeks_total += 1

    def getMonthName(self):
        return self.name

    def getWeek(self, num):
        return self.weeks[num - 1]

    def getWeeksTotal(self):
        return self.weeks_total
```

Every time an instance of the `WeekBlock` class is created, it creates a number of `DayBlock` instances based on the week instance's length parameter.

For example: let's say the number of days in January is 31.  The days for each week would be 7, 7, 7, 7, and 3.

However, when I use `getLength()` in `calendar.py`.  It returns 7 as the length for all 5 weeks when I'm iterating the weeks for the month.  Why am I getting 7 instead of 3 for the last week (when `w` == 4) in this section of my code?

Comment: The problem could be in the `getWeek()` method of whatever type `current_month` is — however you've haven't included that class definition in your question, so no one can tell. You need to have all the relevant code in your question, so please add it.

Comment: I updated classes_calendar.py.  Also, I have tried print() debugging the classes, and I get a similar problem with the getWeek() function.  However, idk what could be causing the issue with my class code.